# javascript evaluate method fails in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have some javascript which is loading an XML document and filtering the elements based on a particular attribute.

The XML structure is similar to the structure below:

```
<locations>
  <region name="metro" title="Metropolitan">
     <location type="HQ">
        <name>Head Office</name>
     </location>
     <location type="NM">
        <name>North Metro</name>
     </location>
  </region> 
  <region name="south" title="Southern region">
     <location type="SR">
        <name>South Regional Office</name>
     </location>
  </region> 
</locations>
```

The javascript is extracting the elements for a specified region, the relevent lines of code are as follows:

```
// supplied region name in this case is "metro"
var _xpath = "/locations/region[@name=\"" + regionName + "\"]";
var _regionList;
// code for IE .... not shown
// code for other browsers
_regionList = mLocationsXmlDoc.evaluate(_xpath, mLocationsXmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

Now this works perfectly well in Firefox, Chrome and Opera… but does not work in Safari.

When executing in Safari, the *_regionList* variable ends up as null with an error message `"TYPE_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 52: The expression could not be converted to return the specified type"` thrown and I can't figure out why.  Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any other expressions that do work in Safari? BTW, there's no point in posting code as a runnable snippet if it doesn't actually run (which this doesn't). Just post it as code.

Comment: There aren't any other pages in the app with a heavy client side focus so can't provide any other examples.  The web site does use a lot of jquery and bootstrap libraries and these all work fine in Safari
Not sure how the runnable snippets ended up in there .. it's my first posting so consider it a rookie mistake

Comment: Fixed. ;-) For code, use the `{}` button, it just indents the code 4 spaces. In–line code is delimited with \`. Checkout my edits, have a play. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I removed the evaluate statement and just traversed the XML structure using the getElementsByTagName and childNodes methods ... a bit more code but Safari is happy with it.
Still none the wiser as to why the evaluate wouldn't work.